# better way to do a rolling aggregation in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some SQL code written in BigQuery which does a rolling sum of a value from current date back three days.

```
with weekly_agg AS
(
select 
    * ,
    UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(event_date)) as timestamps
from
    test.window_test
order by event_date
)
select 
    country,
    event_date
    sum(value) over (partition by country order by timestamps range between 259200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rolling
from
     weekly_agg
```

This seems like a long winded way of solving the issue, is there a better way to accomplish the same thing? The first limitation is you need to hardcode the value 259200 (3 days), you're unable to input a calculation such as ((3600 * 24) * 3). It would be better if I could do a date range within the partition part.

Comment: what exact `data type` of `event_date`?

Comment: it is of type date, the biggest issue is within the partition, is there a way of using dates instead of range between numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first limitation is you need to hardcode the value 259200 (3 days), you're unable to input a calculation such as ((3600 * 24) * 3)

Below is using just `3` days

```
#standardSQL
WITH weekly_agg AS (
  SELECT 
    * ,
    DATE_DIFF(event_date, '2000-01-01', DAY) AS day
  FROM `test.window_test`
  ORDER BY event_date
)
SELECT 
  country,
  event_date,
  SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling
FROM weekly_agg
```

> is there a way of using dates instead of range between numbers?

if you will be using dates instead of range  - this would be some other logic (not a `rolling aggregation`) - something like simple grouping - for example

```
SELECT 
  country,
  event_date,
  SUM(value) 
FROM weekly_agg  
WHERE event_date BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>
GROUP BY country, event_date
```

but that is most likely not what you want ...

Comment: this is fine but is there anyway of not hardcoding the 3 and instead using a variable?

Comment: it must be a literal or parameter. Parameters are not supported in UI - but supported in API, CLI and clients  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries